# Is $B$ finite, countably infinite, or uncountable? $B = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \mathrm{floor}(x)=5) \}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$B =  \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid  \mathrm{floor}(x)=5) \}$

I'm assuming this is the interval $[5,6)$.

My first idea of a proof is the Cantor's Diagonalization Argument. But I'm not sure if that is the right idea. I believe $[5,6)$ is uncountable.

Comment: Notice that $B$ contains every element of $[5,6)$, which for example contains all irrationals between 5 and 6. Surely you know whether this is countable or not.

Comment: Do you know that $[5,6)$, $[0,1)$ and $\Bbb R$ are all the "same size"?

Answer (score 1):

It is in bijection with [0,1) which is uncountable

Answer (score 1):

It is uncountable. Proving by Cantor's Diagonal Argument is not needed since the set $[5,6)$ is the same as $[0,1)$ by subtracting 5 from all it's elements. I assume you have already proved that $[0,1)$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transformations of the function $f(x)=\tan x$ to form a bijection between $(5,6)$ and $\Bbb R$. Since $(5,6)\subseteq [5,6)$, what does this imply about the cardinality of $[5,6)$?

Comment: To be pedantic about it, you should say $f(x)=\tan [(2 x-11)\pi /2].$

Comment: @user254665: I'm under the impression that your expression is just a transformation of the function $f(x)=\tan x$.

Comment: I was very  tired and didn't see  "transformation of" , at all.